# Oracle trigger: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "Column": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created this trigger:

```
 CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER  My_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE  ON product
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.name <> :OLD.name) 
    THEN
    INSERT INTO product_history
    (
        ID,
        PRODUCT_ID,
        NAME
    )
    VALUES
    (
        seq_product.nextval,
        :OLD.PRODUCT_ID,
        :OLD.NAME
    );
    END IF;
END;
```

when I update the table product, I get this error:

```
[Error Code: 4098, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-04098: trigger 'My_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

I execute this query:

```
select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' ;
```

I get:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
```

I can't find  the issue?!

Comment: Does `product_history` actually have a `name` column?

Comment: yes,  it  has ....

Answer (score 1):

The clause

```
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
```

exists so that you can write `OLD.NAME` instead of `:OLD.NAME`, but in your code you are still writing `:OLD.NAME`, which should be the cause that `NAME` is not known anymore.

I'd simply remove the referencing clause and everything should be fine.

Comment: When I remove the referencing clause, I get the same error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier and when I use OLD.NAME instead of :OLD.NAME, I get: PLS-00201: identifier 'OLD.NAME' must be declared!

Comment: I just notice: there is `:NEW.name<>` in your code. Remove the brackets (or whatever they are called).

Comment: The same error is displayed " PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier " :(

Comment: Oops, that was nonsense anyway. I am just working with a framework that uses `<>` with bind variables, so I was confused. Well, I must admit I am out of clues. The trigger refers to the table `product` and you are referencing `:new.name` and `:old.name` which translates to `product.name` and you say that your table `product` contains a column `name`. So everything seems proper. Or are you confusing schemas? Trigger and table are in the same schema and the table `product` in this very schema has a column `Name`, yes? As mentioned, I don't know what else may be happening here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thorsten Kettner, I'll check everything :)